How to get original of my Police Clearance Certificate (PCC) for my 1 year and 3 months stay in France?
I was in France from September 2022 to December 2023 for my masters studies (M2). Then I went back to my home country of India. Now I am applying for long term residence permit of Czech Republic to start my PhD studies in Czech Republic and I downloaded my Criminal record extract from the official website After filling the application form and got it printed.
But during visa interview the official as the Czech embassy told me that they need the official original seal of "Ministère de la Justice Casier Judiciaire National" and original signature of "Le magistrat, chef du service du Casier judiciaire national" Thierry LESCOUARC’H" and not just the printout of the PDF since I am applying for the long term residence permit. They have given me 60 days time to submit this document and they will not start processing my visa till I submit this document!
I contacted the French Embassy in New Delhi and they told me to contact Indian embassy in Paris about my problem. Indian embassy in Paris told me that I can get PCC from VFS Global New Delhi. Since I was not getting any information online, I went to office of VFS New Delhi and they said me that they can only help me with Indian PCC and not French PCC (PCC for my stay in France). So, I said the same to Czech Embassy in New Delhi via e-mail and they said that it's not their problem. Then I e-mailed VFS France and they told me that this website will help me: https://casier-judiciaire.justice.gouv.fr/ (which is same as above mentioned website) and VFS France can't do anything about it!


Have you tried requesting it by mail (instead of email/PDF)? The website seems to allow entering an address outside France. The request is very odd and I am not sure the document you will receive will be any different but at least you won't be the one printing it.

@Relaxed Yes, I did applied for the document to be sent by the post yesterday.

Did you mention to the Czech republic authorities that there's a french government website where the authenticity of the document can be checked (Vérifiable sur ...) ?

@audionuma Yes I did during my Visa Interview but the person still insisted on Original Stamp and Signature!

Any updates on your french PCC? Is apostille and translation required?
I have the similar problem

@CarolFelcitaLobo I don't know yet. I will comment below once the situation becomes clear.

I wish you all the best. Did you receive the French PCC by post, the second time ? If yes, how many days did it take ? Is it same as the one from the email ?
